# Conditional statement does not work when appending a list relative to another

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am trying to remove certain characters from a string.  My way of going about it is to turn the string into a list, iterate through each list and append each good character to a new list and return that new list but for some reason, it doesn't do that.  This is the input:

`"4193 with words"`

and this is the output:

`4193withwords`

In other words, the only part of the code which works is the part of removing the whitespaces.  Here is my entire code:

```
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, str: str) -> int:
        illegal_char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&' '*', '(', ')', '=', '+', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|']
        new_list = []

        integer_list = list(str)

        for i in range(len(integer_list)):
            if integer_list[i] != any(illegal_char):
                new_list.append(integer_list[i])
        output = ''.join(new_list)
        output = output.replace(' ', '')

        return output
```

Comment: This part is completely wrong: `if integer_list[i] != any(illegal_char)`. See what `any` does in the documentation.

Comment: @zvone it returns a boolean value, which is what I am checking for.

Comment: You are checking whether `integer_list[i]` equals `True`. Is that really what you want to check?

Comment: I'm trying to check for whether `integer_list[i]` equals to any of the elements in `illegal_char` list.  How should I go about it?  I don't want to make a nested for loop for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `join` on a list-comprehension. What you need is a membership check in list and form string with only those characters you need:

```
''.join([x for x in s if x not in illegal_char]).replace(' ', '')
```

Note that I have renamed your string to `s`, because `str` is a built-in.

Also to add, if you can include space as `illegal_char` you can avoid `replace` at the end.

Comment: I forgot to mention.  In this snippet, how do I also check if the first non-whitespace character is an integer?  Because if not, I want to return 0.

Comment: `s = s if s.lstrip()[0].isdigit() else 0`.

Comment: Thanks man.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well.

Comment: @OnurOzbek, You already have my upvote. Someone downvoted and hence it shows as zero. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this is a very complicated way of replacing some characters. I suggest you, to learn some regex, as it could help you alot. There is a regex library for python called re.

This would be my solution:

```
import re
mytext = "4193 with words"
newtext = re.sub("\s", "", mytext)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've just upvoted your answer. If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?